# questions on $L_p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis

With the following setting $L^p(X,M,\mu)=\{f:X\to\mathbb{R}:f \text{ is measurable and }\|f\|_p<\infty\}$ where $\|.\|_p=\bigg(\int|.|^pd\mu\bigg)^\frac{1}{p}$ and $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space.

On page 182 on Folland's Real analysis, we have the following,

> Suppose $a>0,b>0,$ and $0<p<1$. For $t>0$ we have $t^{p-1}>(a+t)^{p-1}$, and by integrating from $0$ to $b$ we obtain $a^p+b^p>(a+t)^p$.

I couldn't understand where the last inequality arrived from. Suppose we integrating $t^{p-1}>(a+t)^{p-1}$ with respect to some fixed measure $\mu$ we have $\int_{[0,b]}t^{p-1}d\mu> \int_{[0,b]}(a+t)^{p-1} d\mu$. But I guess if I assuming $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and integrating with respect to $t$, $\int^b_{0}t^{p-1}dt=\dfrac{b^p}{p}> \dfrac{(a+b)^p}{p}-\dfrac{a^p}{p}=\int^b_{0}(a+t)^{p-1} dt$?

But what allows me to swap $d\mu$ to $dt$? Thanks!

Comment: This argument simplify things a little. consider $\phi(t)=(1+t)^p-t^p$, $t\geq0$. then $\phi'(t)=p((1+t)^{p-1}-t^{p-1})$. As $0<p<1$, $p-1<0$ and so $x\mapsto x^{p-1}$ is monotone decreasing. Thus, $\phi'(t)<0$. consequently $\phi$ is monotone decreasing and so, $\phi(t)\leq \phi(0)=1$ for all $t\geq0$

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks for the comment! I believe the inequality holds, but I guess I don't know why we can just integrate it. But I think I get it now, it's because it is a continuous real valued function which means it is integrable and its integral is the same as Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Why would you integrate against à measure $\mu$? Folland just writes "integrate" ... this often means with respect to the Lebesgue measure (ie taking the antiderivative) which is ok as soon as the functions are locally integrable

Comment: @LL3.14 I see, I must not understand the meaning correctly, thanks for pointing that out.